# Javascript markers with info window on switch statement

Tags: javascript, switch-statement, infowindow, markers

Hi I have some options such as 'sunny','snowy','rainy' on the menu and i need to add a marker with an info window for each of these options displaying a different picture on each case. I am trying to work it out but it seems that my code doesn't work. Any advice ? Thanks.

```
     function dropweather()
   {
var contentString='Weather';
var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
  content: contentString
 });
var lat = prompt ('Latitude'); var lng = prompt('Longitude');
switch(document.getElementById('weatherkind').value)
{
    case 'sunny':
        new google.maps.Marker({
            position: new google.maps.LatLng(lat,lng),
            map:map,
            icon:'sun.jpe'                       
        });
        break;
     case 'rainy':
        new google.maps.Marker({
            position: new google.maps.LatLng(lat,lng),
            map:map,
            icon:'rain.jpe'                       
        });
        break;
         case 'cloudy':
        new google.maps.Marker({
            position: new google.maps.LatLng(lat,lng),
            map:map,
            icon:'clouds.jpg'   ,

        });
        break;
   }
 google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
infowindow.open(map,marker);
    });

     }

     google.maps.event.addDomListener(window,'load',initialize);
```

what happens is that the picture is getting displayed for instance if i chose sunny the sun.jpg picture is getting displayed on the location that i chose. But what I need is a marker with an info window and show the picture in that info window. Any advice ? thanks.

Comment: check you switch value is coming in right way.

Comment: can you post a fiddle?

Comment: hey i ve never used fiddle, but what happens if i delete the icon element from the marker, a marker is created when i chose one of the options but without an info window. any advice ?

Answer (score 0):

var marker = map.addMarker({
            lat: -13.004333,
            lng: -38.494333,
            title: 'Loop, Inc.',
            infoWindow: {
                content: "**Loop, Inc.** 795 Park Ave, Suite 120
San Francisco, CA 94107
"
            }
        });

choose image with your condition and add it in the image src of infoWindow . I hope it should work for you.

refference from [Google Maps How to add Image into InfoWindow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18333671/google-maps-how-to-add-image-into-infowindow)

Comment: hey thanks for your reply. but the thing is that the info windows are not created.so lets say if i chose one of my options the marker is created but when i click on the marker the info window does not appear.

Comment: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/infowindow-simple  it will suerly help you.

Comment: I am using it and i can understand how it works thanks but the thing is that i am using these switch statements in order to generate the marker, the marker is created but the infowindow is not.