# I want to customize the google-maps infowindow to have an image

Tags: javascript, html, css

Im using googleMaps api, everything is working correctly. Im not sure how to add a image to the infowindow.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Here's a question very similar to yours: http://stackoverflow.com/q/18333671/3345375

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check [here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/infowindows#add) for API documentation.Just call setContent() and it should do good.